# When would PySpark executor libraries be different than the driver?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, executor

I was following [this guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/successful-spark-submits-for-python-projects-53012ca7405a) (apologies for Medium post) and it showed how you could separately package up your python env and libraries for your Spark executors and your driver. When would it apply that you would expect different libraries to be needed for each? I think a simple, but concrete, example would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a scenario in which you need to send a email as a notification to users once a spark job is completed now this particular function for  sending the email will be always executed on driver. , So the `smtplib` and related libraries are needed to be available on the driver only  as the executors are not going to send the emails .

Comment: Great example. Would it be generally safe to assume any code that isn't part of a UDF would likely not be run at all in the executors?

Comment: This will be a correct assumption which will be valid in almost all scenarios , there can be a few exceptions to this . I will try to get some examples for that